# Boolean - Int conversion in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is there no built-in way to convert between boolean - int in Kotlin? I am talking about the usual:

```
true -> 1
false -> 0
```

If not, what is an idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: What would be a use case for this?

Comment: Making a request to an API that returns 0 or 1 for a field that should clearly be true/false. At the same time, I also make other requests to similar APIs for the same type of field that give me back true/false. I'd like to share the code that handles that response from all APIs.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can write an extension function of Boolean like

```
fun Boolean.toInt() = if (this) 1 else 0
```

Comment: Similarly convert Int to Boolean in Kotlin:                                                                                           
fun Int.toBoolean() = this == 1

Comment: @AndroidGuy no, please dont! This is subtly different from the usual C-logic where integers not 0 or 1 are considered true. Better to say: Int.toBoolean() = this != 0

Answer (score 36):

writing a function for this task for every project can be a little tedious.
there is a kotlin function that you can use it to achieve this.

with `compareTo` if variable is **greater than** input it will output **1**, if **equal to** it will output **0** and if **less than** input it will output **-1**

so you can use it for this task like this:

```
v.compareTo(false) // 0 or 1
```

Comment: Very clean solution.

Comment: Worth adding that if `true` was the argument ("input"), then the result is either **`-1`** for `false.compareTo(true)`, or **`0`** for `true.compareTo(true)` which is not helpful in most cases. (So `false` has to be the argument.)

Answer (score 18):

You could extend `Boolean` with an **extension property** in this case:

```
val Boolean.int 
     get() = if (this) 1 else 0
```

Now you can simply do `true.int` in your code

Answer (score 4):

No there is no way to convert. you only can convert by following below code

```
 val output = if (input) 1 else 0
```

Comment: Better to do this as an etension funtion

Answer (score 4):

> Making a request to an API that returns 0 or 1 for a field that should clearly be true/false. At the same time, I also make other requests to similar APIs for the same type of field that give me back true/false. I'd like to share the code that handles that response from all APIs.

In this case I think using converter of your mapping library (jackson, etc) will be best option.

In plain Kotlin you can use extension function/property for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

use this :

```
val Boolean?.int
    get() = if (this != null && this) 1 else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

int to boolean :

```
    var intTemp:Int = 1
    val boolTemp:Boolean = intTemp == 1 // true if intTemp is 1 and false if it is 0
```

boolean to int :

```
    val boolTemp :Boolean = false
    val intTemp :Int = if (boolTemp) 1 else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

True example (false is implied):

```
val boolValue = 1
val booleanResult = boolValue != 0  // true
```